# Animating letters easily?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, svg

http://cl.ly/YXIK (image of what I try to animate)

I'm a graphic designer and beginner in CSS and HTML, who is trying to animate the Arabic letters to convey how they would be written in a certain style (calligraphy).

I want to find a way to animate 28 and more letters easily. I tried several techniques but non worked. I'm now trying with Adobe Edge Animate (http://cl.ly/YRdZ), but still having problems.

**I also need help defining my brush size, angle, and speed of the stroke to mimic the way a calligrapher would draw the letters.**

my questions:

- What is the best and most economical way to animate those letters? (softwares or secret recipes)
- Will generating one CSS or one JS is enough to animate each and every letters?
- How can I read the SVG file? I couldn't understand the numbers at all!

Comment: I think you're on the right track.  SVG is definitely the way to do this.  You're going to have to pick your start and end points.  I don't know of any software that can do this.  From there, you can probably code something to tween, but again I don't know of any off the shelf tool to help with that.

Comment: Hello, I discovered that I won't be able to use stroke only SVGs. I will need a tool to help me animate the full shape with the fill. Do you know how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using this library:: http://maxwellito.github.io/vivus/

```
new Vivus('my-letter-id', {type: 'oneByOne', duration: 500}, myCallback);
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this!
I would want to know how to do multiple paths? Should I name the paths in illustrator and use the same name in js?